# JavaFX tooltip on editable cell

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a `TableView` with editable cells. I use the recommended JavaFx callback to achieve editable cells.

```
myCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Student>forTableColumn());
```

I want to add a tooltip to each of these editable cells, so I have to make my own Callback.
Is it possible to extend the above Callback to add functionality for adding a ToolTip or do I have to write my own from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid for this you will have to make your own TableCell and then assign it to your TableColumn - myCol.

A simple example is as shown, `you need to override all the functions of the TableCell as well :)`

```
class EditingCell extends TableCell<Student, String> {

    private TextField textField;

    public EditingCell() {
       setToolTip("YOUR MESSAGE");
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
                Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                    if (!arg2) {
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
}
```

and then add this to your TableColumn

```
Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory =
         new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
             public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                return new EditingCell();
             }
         };
```

and

```
firstNameCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
```

**Don't forget to make your table as editable !**

```
table.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: Does this way allow for editing functionality (Cell turns into an EditText when clicked on) ? It looks like this just adds the tooltip ability to a normal table cell.

Comment: Please go through the complete example, you need to override the functions of TableCell class :)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, you could add the reference link of the code you posted. Also to complete the answer you could attach a tooltip to textfield as the OP wants.

Comment: @UlukBiy I first showed the OP the way to add tooltip to the cell (check my edit), then he asked me to make it editable, so I just copied it from the docs and pasted here :)

Comment: Awesome, I will try this out today, and get back to you!